# delete entire line after first whitespace on every line

Tags: whitespace, multiple-lines

I have a file (around 1.6 million lines) which formatted like this:

```
-0.00697468 0 -1.95966e-49 101325 -3.06381  
-0.00697468 0 -1.95966e-49 101325 -3.06381  
-0.00697468 0 -1.95966e-49 101325 -3.06381  
. . .
```

After some thousand lines, the format will be changed (no minus sign on the first character), like this:

```
0.453945 -2.14126e-54 3.40152e-49 101325 214.355  
0.453945 -2.14126e-54 3.40152e-49 101325 214.355  
0.453945 -2.14126e-54 3.40152e-49 101325 214.355  
. . .
```

So, how to delete the entire line, after the first whitespace on every line?
I have tried to search but couldn't get any answer that I want. Thanks!
(Note: some lines have different number of character, hence that I cannot simply delete some characters from the end of the line on every line)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two commands below will reduce every line to the first sequence of non-whitespace character followed by a space:

```
from
0.453945 -2.14126e-54 3.40152e-49 101325 214.355

to
0.453945 <-- space
```

But your question is a little confusing so I'm not sure I understood what you want.

With a substitution:

```
:%s/\(\S\+\s\).*/\1
```

With a macro:

```
:%normal! WD
```

Comment: and if you want to delete those trailing single whitespaces left behind on every line, use    :%s/ *$//     <- yes, that is a single whitespace character between / and *

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to delete entire line starting with a space, This pattern will be useful.

```
:g/^\s.*/d
```

- `g` -global
- `^` - start of the line
- `\s` - space
- `.*` - anything after that
- `d` - delete

If you want the starting whitespace to remain, but delete the remaining content, you can use,

```
:%s/^\(\s\+\).*/\1/g
```

Comment: First one doesn't work, get "Pattern not found: ^\s.*" using both vim/vi

Comment: It works for me. Why did you add quotes at the end?

Comment: that quote at the end was due to my sentence.  first quote opens before Pattern

Comment: try ':g/^ .*/d'. you could replace \s with space itself and try

Comment: also does not work, however this does: :%s/ .*//

Comment: I misunderstood the question. question mentions 'after first whitespace', i understood 'first character as whitespace'. yours is correct.